# Convert string dot notation into javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, formatting

I'm working on an existing project that takes query parameters in an oddly formatted string dot notation. But they must be converted into objects before processing. This is currently being performed with conditionals on specific keys by name.

How can this be performed dynamically? Below you will find an example of the input and desired output.

Input:

```
{ 
    date.gte: '2019-01-01', 
    date.lt: '2020-01-01' 
}
```

Output:

```
{
    date: {
        gte: '2019-01-01',
        lt: '2020-01-01'
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Which part specifically have you had an issue with?

Comment: I attempted an implementation using Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {  } where I would attempt see if key included a period and if so key,split('.') . Then take those results and return them. Just was not sure if that was an efficient or proper path.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] then. What efficiency is needed? What would *"proper"* mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `reduce` and `split` methods to split each key into array and build nested structure based on that array.

```js
const data = {
  'date.gte': '2019-01-01',
  'date.lt': '2020-01-01'
}

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  k.split('.').reduce((a, e, i, ar) => {
    return a[e] || (a[e] = ar[i + 1] ? {} : v)
  }, r)

  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

By you saying "oddly formatted string dot notation" I assume you mean `"date.gte"` & `"date.lt"`

```js
const input = {
    "date.gte": "2019-01-01",
    "date.lt": "2020-01-01"
};

const res = Object.keys(input).reduce(
    (result, current) => {
        const [, operator] = current.split(".");

        result.date[operator] = input[current];

        return result;
    },
    { date: {} }
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: fails for: const input = {
    "date.gte.a": "2019-01-01",
    "date.lt.b": "2020-01-01"
};

Comment: @ssBarBee the question did not mention about that random input.

Comment: he said: This is currently being performed with conditionals on specific keys by name. - I would assume that they have weird inputs :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's an improvement on Dan's answer that doesn't rely on knowing the key-value pairs in the original object. As much as Nenad's answer blows this out of the water, I worked for too long on this to not post it :)

```js
const formatter = (weirdObject, s = '.') => Object.keys(weirdObject).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const [parent, child] = cur.split(s);
  if (!acc[parent]) acc[parent] = {};
  acc[parent][child] = weirdObject[cur];
  return acc;
}, {});

// -- Demonstration:

const input1 = {
  "date.gte": "2019-01-01",
  "date.lt": "2020-01-01"
};

const input2 = {
  "person:name": "Matt",
  "person:age": 19
};

const res1 = formatter(input1);
const res2 = formatter(input2, ':');

console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
```

Comment: nice! its defiantly more readable than the top voted answer :)